# React Native array of dictionary

Tags: react-native

Can anyone tell me how to initialise the array in constructor for following structure?

I am doing it by

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
```

But I think this is wrong.

Here is my data structure

```
[
    {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
    {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
    {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
 ]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing the right way.

If the data is from the `API / 3rd Party` try setting the data from `componentDidMount()` leaving the initial data state an empty array and setting the data using this.setState({ stateArrayName : val}).

Else if you have some static data or data before hand you can directly store that in the state array.

```
    constructor(props)
    super(props){
    this.state = {
    data : [
    {
    name : 'abc',
    data: ['item1', 'item2'],
    etc : 'abc'
    },
{
    name : 'abc',
    data: ['item1', 'item2'],
    etc : 'abc'
    },
{
    name : 'abc',
    data: ['item1', 'item2'],
    etc : 'abc'
    },
{
    name : 'abc',
    data: ['item1', 'item2'],
    etc : 'abc'
    }]
    }
```